# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) libwebviewchromium.so

Tags: android

Getting many crashes in play console but not on Crashlytics . I know this question has been already asked here but i checked all of them were kinda old . I think this crash is due to some bug in chromium or android update because it only showing after 30 July 2019 .

Crashes only on Android 4.4 , 5.0 ,5.1 & 6.0 versions.

Here is the log:-

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

libwebviewchromium.so
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000102ecf4  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/arm64/libwebviewchromium.so
  #01  pc 000000000102f6ec  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/lib/arm64/libwebviewchromium.so (Java_org_chromium_content_browser_webcontents_WebContentsImpl_nativeGetURL+40)
```

Here is the log of second crash:-

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)  

WebViewGoogle.apk
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000682444  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk
  #01  pc 00000000006b0d9c  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk
```

Can anyone please tell why and what can be done?

Answer (score 4):

This is an Android Webview Error there is nothing you can do about it. These crashes were reported by developer multiple time On Google Developers Forum here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/Q-edauZ27g8 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/loKfUDr2w3E/Cz7OD90QAQAJ
but there is no fix till date.

Answer (score 1):

This error in admob ads you can fixed with update system webview

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview

Answer (score 0):

Same Error i also seeing in console but no one reply in stackoverflow no solution found it decrease my app ranking